# 403 Forbidden on Server (API, Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl

local works but in production it returns 403. Same PHP and Laravel version. Is there anything i can do?

```php
$url = 'https://admin.appmax.com.br/api/v3/order/'.$order_id.'?access-token='.$token;            
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-Type: application/json'],
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);`
```

I did all the tests, it doesn't work only in production.

Comment: is your server IP whitelisted to make calls to the ``admin.appmax.com.br`` domain? Probably you're not !

Comment: I also think that's it but support says the problem is on my side. :/

Comment: Did you have to set some kind of credentials in your env file?

Comment: no, in this case I declare in the variables... Location also stops working if I activate the VPN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was server permission, they solved it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting CURLOPT_POST to true, which indicates that you want to send a POST request, but you're also setting CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST to 'GET', which indicates that you want to send a GET request. You should remove the CURLOPT_POST option since you're sending a GET request.

Neither you're passing the access token as a header. You're passing it as a query parameter in the URL.

Also, check the response for errors before processing it using curl_error.

The following should work.

```
$url = 'https://admin.appmax.com.br/api/v3/order/'.$order_id.'?access-token='.$token;            
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => ['Content-Type: application/json'],
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if ($response === false) {
    echo 'cURL Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
    return;
}

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if ($httpCode != 200) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $httpCode;
    return;
}

curl_close($curl);
// process $response
```